# I don’t know how to simplify the derivative of $f(x) = -x^\frac{4}{3} + 4x^\frac{1}{3}$ or f(x) = -x^4/3 + 4x^1/3

Tags: calculus

I need to get f’(x) of f(x). I know that $f(x)=-x^\frac{4}{3} + 4x^\frac{1}{3}$ and $f’(x) = -\frac{4}{3}x^\frac{1}{3} + \frac{4}{3}x^\frac{-2}{3}$ when it’s not simplified.

When I tried simplifying f’(x), I got:

$$f’(x) = \frac{-4x^\frac{1}{3}+4x^\frac{-2}{3}}{3}$$
$$f’(x) = \frac{-4x^\frac{1}{3}+4}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$f’(x) = \frac{4(-x^\frac{1}{3}+1)}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$f’(x) = \frac{-4(x^\frac{1}{3}-1)}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$$

However, the correct simplified form is:
$$\frac{-4(x-1)}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$$

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to not arrive at the correct simplified form of f’(x). Even if we don’t have to simplify the derivative, we’re required in school to do so.

Comment: I would say your answer before you tried any simplification is also a valid simplification of the derivative. When it comes to expressions of this type, there’s no commonly agreed upon form that a simplification should look like. It’s not like rationalizing the denominator. So for example in a test, unless the question gives you explicit hint that your final answer should look a certain way, you shouldn’t be expected to be able to know which form your answer should look like, and if you got points taken off for missing it in that scenario, it’s your teacher bullshitting you.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f^{\prime} = \frac{-4x^{\frac{1}{3}} + 4x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{3} = \frac{-4x^{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}} + 4x}{3x^{-\frac{-2}{3}}}= \frac{-4(x-1)}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}} $$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = -x^{\frac{4}{3}}+4x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. as you correctly computed $f'(x) = -\frac{4}{3} x^{\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{4}{3} x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

What you need is a little bit of manipulations. $-4x^{\frac{1}{3}} = -4x^{-\frac{2}{3}} x^{1}$

in this way we have $$\frac{-4x^{-\frac{2}{3}} x^{1}+4x^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{3}$$

we factor out the term $-4x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ and we get :

$$\frac{-4x^{-\frac{2}{3}}\left( x-1 \right)}{3} = \frac{-4\left( x-1 \right)}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

I hope this helps

P.S. pay attention at what you did here:
$$f’(x) = \frac{-4x^\frac{1}{3}+4x^\frac{-2}{3}}{3}$$
$$f’(x) = \frac{-4x^\frac{1}{3}+4}{3x^\frac{2}{3}}$$
you cannot move $x^{\frac{-2}{3}}$ at the denominator like that . In this way you are dividing also $-4x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ by $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ which is different form what you had